# Submitting form with mechanize ends with decoding/encoding accented characters issues

Tags: html, python-3.x, mechanize

I am working on this script which submit random created text within a form (input text area). The issue I am having is related to accented characters, which after sending, the frontend renders it incorrectly, the following is the code related to this

```
br["message"] = TextGenerator.text() // Generate a text string
try:
    br[quickreply] = 1
    br[forcepost] = 1
except:
    pass

response = br.submit()
```

TextGenerator.text() returns the following string (as example):
Cauterização

Frontend renders the text as:
CauterizaÃ§Ã£o

I am using python 3.7.2 rather than 2.x because I thought 3.x.x would automatically handle this encoding/decoding use cases.

How should this be addressed?

Comment: What's the frontend?

Comment: @pguardiario vBulletin 4.2.3

Comment: Check the doctype and meta charset and make sure it says uft8

Comment: @pguardiario metadata on vBulletin says windows-1252

Comment: If you can change that to utf8 that's probably the best bet. Otherwise you can try to convert your python string to that.